# How many users have 2 or more transactions in period of n-days without skipping even a day

Tags: postgresql

I need help to find and count orders in certain consecutive period of time from 'sales_track' table from users that has minimum of two or more transactions (rephrase: How many users have 2 or more transactions in period of n-days without skipping even a day)

sales_track

```
sales_tx_id | u_id | create_date | item_id | price
------------|------|-------------|---------|---------
 ffff-0291  | 0001 | 2019-08-01  | 0300    | 5.00
 ffff-0292  | 0001 | 2019-08-01  | 0301    | 2.50
 ffff-0293  | 0002 | 2019-08-01  | 0209    | 3.50
 ffff-0294  | 0003 | 2019-08-01  | 0020    | 1.00
 ffff-0295  | 0001 | 2019-08-02  | 0301    | 2.50
 ffff-0296  | 0001 | 2019-08-02  | 0300    | 5.00
 ffff-0297  | 0001 | 2019-08-02  | 0209    | 3.50
 ffff-0298  | 0002 | 2019-08-02  | 0300    | 5.00
```

For simplicity sake sample is for two consecutive days (period of time is between 2019-08-01 and 2019-08-02) only, in real operation I would have to search eg. 10 consecutive days transaction.

I'm able so far to find the minimum two or more transactions.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT (user_id) FROM sales_track WHERE created_at BETWEEN 
('2019-08-01') AND ('2019-08-02') 
GROUP BY u_id HAVING COUNT (sales_tx_id) >= 2;
```

The output I'm looking for is like:

```
 u_id | tx_count | tx_amount  
------|----------|------------
 0001 | 5        | 18.50
```

Thank you in advance your help.

Comment: What is the problem? Just add SUM(price). BTW: in your example 2 is a solution as well: 2 entries https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5f93b30bebd14b0d719304a6fd730bc7; Otherwise: What do you mean with "consecutive"

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Problem is the "consecutive n-days" part. Eg. need to find users that has minimal two or more transactions in 10 days without skipping a day.

I'm using postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.3, pgAdmin 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=49888352d79528d4e6c1b64f5e63776c)

First: My extended data set:

```
sales_tx_id | user_id | created_at | item_id | price
:---------- | :------ | :--------- | :------ | ----:
ffff-0291   | 0001    | 2019-08-01 | 0300    |  5.00
ffff-0292   | 0001    | 2019-08-01 | 0301    |  2.50
ffff-0293   | 0002    | 2019-08-01 | 0209    |  3.50
ffff-0294   | 0003    | 2019-08-01 | 0020    |  1.00
ffff-0295   | 0001    | 2019-08-02 | 0301    |  2.50
ffff-0296   | 0001    | 2019-08-02 | 0300    |  5.00
ffff-0297   | 0001    | 2019-08-02 | 0209    |  3.50
ffff-0298   | 0002    | 2019-08-02 | 0300    |  5.00
ffff-0299   | 0001    | 2019-08-05 | 0209    |  3.50
ffff-0300   | 0001    | 2019-08-05 | 0020    |  1.00
ffff-0301   | 0001    | 2019-08-06 | 0209    |  3.50
ffff-0302   | 0001    | 2019-08-06 | 0020    |  1.00
ffff-0303   | 0001    | 2019-08-07 | 0209    |  3.50
ffff-0304   | 0001    | 2019-08-07 | 0020    |  1.00
ffff-0305   | 0002    | 2019-08-08 | 0300    |  5.00
ffff-0306   | 0002    | 2019-08-08 | 0301    |  2.50
ffff-0307   | 0001    | 2019-08-09 | 0209    |  3.50
ffff-0308   | 0001    | 2019-08-09 | 0020    |  1.00
ffff-0309   | 0002    | 2019-08-09 | 0300    |  5.00
ffff-0310   | 0002    | 2019-08-09 | 0301    |  2.50
ffff-0311   | 0001    | 2019-08-10 | 0209    |  3.50
ffff-0312   | 0001    | 2019-08-10 | 0020    |  1.00
ffff-0313   | 0002    | 2019-08-10 | 0300    |  5.00
```

User 1 has 3 streaks:

- 2019-08-01, 2019-08-02
- 2019-08-05, 2019-08-06, 2019-08-07
- 2019-08-09, 2019-08-10

User 2:

- Has transaction at 2019-08-01, 2019-08-02, but only one each date, so that does not count
- Has streak on 2019-08-08, 2019-08-09 (2019-08-10 has only one transaction, does not extend streak)

So we are expecting 4 rows: 3 for each user 1 streak, 1 for user 2

```
SELECT                                       -- 4
    user_id, 
    SUM(count), 
    SUM(price), 
    MIN(created_at) AS consecutive_start
FROM (
    SELECT *,                                -- 3
       SUM(is_in_same_group) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) AS group_id
    FROM (
        SELECT                               -- 2
            *,
           (lag(created_at, 1, created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) + 1 <> created_at)::int as is_in_same_group
        FROM (
            SELECT                           -- 1
                created_at,
                user_id,
                COUNT(*),
                SUM(price) AS price
            FROM
                sales_track
            WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2019-08-11'
            GROUP BY created_at, user_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
        ) s
    ) s
) s
GROUP BY user_id, group_id
```

1. Grouping all (`created_at`, `user_id`) groups and remove those with `COUNT() < 2`
2. the [`lag()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) allows to get the value of the previous record within one ordered group. The group here is the `user_id`. The check here is: If the current created_at value is the next to the previous (current + 1) then `0`, else `1`.
3. Now we can use the cummulative `SUM()` window function to sum these values: The value increases if the gap is too big (if value is `1`) otherwise it is the same value as the previous date. Now we got a `group_id` for all dates that only differ +1
4. Finally these groups can be grouped for `SUM()` and `COUNT()`

Comment: Thank you again for quick response, as always! However I have updated the question my best to avoid misunderstanding. It's the "consecutive days" part that is very hard. How many users have 2 or more transactions in period of n-days without skipping even a day.

Comment: @Worka Ok, but why is user 2 not in your expected output

Comment: user 2 is not expected because only have 1 transaction per day during asked period.

Comment: @Worka Hm, he has 1 on 2019-08-1 and 1 on 2019-08-02

Comment: user 2 needs to have minimum 2 or more transactions per day for consecutive n-days (this case is 2 days, could be 10 days, 30 days etc)

Comment: @Worka Added solution and explanation

Comment: I'm dying to try this on my production table however got an ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer
LINE 8: ...) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) + 1 <> cre...

Comment: @Worka this should work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d9ccdfe1d3680da6bff92a3c9f9a5809 The + 1 is only for column type date. You did not mention, that you are using timestamp for it (why is that?).

Comment: The created_at was using timestamp with timezone because there are branches overseas for operations.

Comment: you can do: 'your timestamp value'::date (an explicit cast into date) and then + 1 (which I would prefer!) or the (+ interval '1 day') thing as I showed

Comment: Sorry took so long to reply, was trying to implement this to my database. I appreciate you and @forpas' effort to help me GREATLY. If I am to change the x's and n's to more definitive: *consecutive two or more transactions between 2019-06-01 and 2019-07-31* (50 days streak) I would just have to change the 1st create date condition?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. What is x and n?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197820/discussion-between-worka-and-s-man).